# Better way to write a polling function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I wrote a polling function to check the value of `reg_result` variable for 120 seconds.

```
reg_result = 0
while_timeout = time.time() + 120
while reg_result is not "REGISTERED" and time.time() < while_timeout:
    reg_result = LeshanObj.validate_reg_time(parameter_1)
```

Is there any other better way of writing a polling method?

Is it possible by not using a `while` loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a library in python Polling(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polling/0.3.0)
You can use this

```
from polling import TimeoutException, poll
try:
    poll(lambda: reg_result=='REGISTERED', timeout=120, step=1)
except TimeoutException as tee:
    print "Value was not registered"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This prints the Value no matter wether exception is faced or not. It will wait to do the polling but in the end will run the print statement either way.

Comment: There is now a better alternative: see https://pypi.org/project/polling2/

Comment: @TimDowty this project is just as broken as the original.