# How to keep listening to api data and when that data change execute a code

Tags: python, api

I'm actually new to dealing with api and writing scripts in general, i created this python code to get a specific data from the api then write that data in a .txt file

```py
import requests
import json
azura_API = requests.get('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/nowplaying/1')
data = azura_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
song_text = parse_json['now_playing']['song']['text']
print("Now Playing:", song_text)
with open('/**/**/song.txt','w') as fd:
    fd.write(song_text)
```

What i couldn't figure out is how to keep it listening to the api and when there is a data change i want it to overwrite the .txt file with that new data, i don't want to run the script every second or two with a cron job or a daemon because i don't want to stress the system.

Edit:
I just knew about polling it seems that it can do what i want i just don't know how to adjust my code to work with it, i will try to figure it out and update the code, any help that would be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to write a polling function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713234/better-way-to-write-a-polling-function-in-python)

Comment: "*i don't want to run the script every second or two with a cron job or a daemon because i don't want to stress the system.*" This sentence indicates to me that you seem to know the answer already, so I think this begs a follow-up question: why not just set a `cron` job or daemon to poll the API at longer intervals than just a "*second or two*"? Why not every 30 seconds, or a minute? If my assumption is correct that the string `nowplaying` is indicative of a music-related service, why not every 2-3 minutes?

Comment: @esqew because the data in .txt file will be used in a video stream that's why i wanted it to be in real time or as close as possible and also i don't have enough ram (1gb)  i didn't want to use the cron job or the daemon approach because i think this is going to use so much ram for just pulling this "little" data from the api